# Is watching teachers of opposite sex in digital learning is also haram?

Tags: halal-haram, practical-islam, sharia

Is learning digitally through YouTube is haram ? assume I m a girl, I m learning from a male teacher in YouTube. Is that also come under haram?

Answer (score -1):

No, it isn't. This is not a relationship. It's just like reading a book.